# setting Address Book image with MacRuby

Tags: macos, image, addressbook, macruby

I am trying to set my user's Address Book Image with MacRuby. Here is what I have so far:

```
framework 'ScriptingBridge'
framework 'AppKit'

download = "/path.png"
data   = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(download)
bitmap = NSBitmapImageRep.imageRepWithData(data)
final  = bitmap.representationUsingType(NSTIFFFileType, properties: nil)

book = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.addressbook")
book.myCard.setImage(final)
```

I have also tried `book.myCard.setImage(final.base64Encoding)`, by the way.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have an **NSImage**

```
myImage = NSImage.alloc.initWithContentsOfFile(download)
book = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.addressbook")
book.myCard.setImage(myImage)
```